# Send multiple very small packets or fewer large packets?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am currently working on a simple application that transfers screenshots across sockets. I get the screenshot by instantiating and using the Robot class as follows:

```
private Robot robot;
public Robot getRobot(){
    if(robot == null){
        try{
            robot = new Robot();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    return robot;
}

public BufferedImage screenshot(){
    return getRobot().createScreenCapture(getScreenRectangle());
}

public byte[] getBytes(BufferedImage image){
    byte[] data = null;
    try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
    }catch(IOException e){}
    return data;
}
```

I then use the `getBytes` method above to convert the `BufferedImage` to a byte array which is then written to the socket output stream. The image is an average of 500KB. Would it be more efficient to split this 500KB into smaller segments of say 5KB or would it be better to keep it in larger chunks of say 30KB. My main aim here is speed and accuracy of delivery. I would also appreciate any reasoning of why either way would be more effective in these terms that the other.

Comment: If you're using TCP, accuracy will not be a problem. I would think that choosing a packet size close to the TCP stack's buffer size would be ideal.

Comment: Why don't you simply test it with different sizes?

Comment: @SeanBright and what is the TCP stack's buffer size? Is it system dependent?

Comment: It is system dependent, yes. [This question discusses how to get it on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865069/how-to-find-the-socket-buffer-size-of-linux).

Comment: Why not just write directly to the output stream of the socket? The socket will take care of buffering.

Comment: If you're using TCP the packet size, or rather segment size, is completely out of your control anyway. Just write. TCP will take care of the MTU and MSS for you.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that TCP doesn't do for you already?

Answer (score 3):

> Send multiple very small packets or fewer large packets?

This is a very common question in apps that QoS play an important role. I think that there isnt a correct answer, only an implemetation that adapts better to your requeriments.

A few aspects that you might consider:

- Bigger packets reduces de % of overhead over data.
- Bigger packets has a bigger impact when there is an error at recieving or sending data (corrupted data).
- Smaller packets should be used for an application that provides better response to user.
- In some applications where the traffic is important and necessary to process information quickly, instead of sending the entire image for each frame, portions of the image varied should be sent, using appropriate protocols.

Comment: This is actually quite a good answer.  Why would anyone downvote it?  Anyway, I'm gonna upvote it, so there:)

Answer (score 2):

The network packet size is limited by what is called [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit), you can't send a packet bigger than mtu. The mtu, as you can check from the link, is not that big (I believe 1500 bytes is the more common MTU for Ethernet). This is for the network side; on the java side deciding the segment size could depend on the number of images transmitted concurrently (if you send 100 image concurrently you have 100 segments allocated).

My suggestion is to try with a segment size slightly less that MTU (I guess you are using TCP/IP so you must consider TCP and IP header size) and see what happens.

**Edit**: some comments point out (correctly) that form the java perspective the MTU does not affect how the data should be chunked; this is true for packet bigger than MTU since the TCP/IP layer breaks larger chunks of data in smaller units; but the poster wants to know if there is a "best" buffer size; and the response is that over the MTU there is no benefit (for network transmission) in increasing the buffer size at the java side

Comment: I appreciate the help. Could you give me some guidance on the header size of each packet?

Comment: yes, you can look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846077/size-of-empty-udp-and-tcp-packet the sum of headers (ethernet + ip + tcp ) is about 64 byte

Comment: @rodit it's about 50-60 bytes and not something you can change.  It's not a detail you should be worrying about unless your messages are close to this size.

Comment: MTU is irrelevant from the perspective of Java. TCP provides stream oriented data transfer: just write into the stream of the socket and the socket will take care of buffering and sending data.

Comment: There is no actual reason to limit your writes to a size somewhat less than a guess at the MTU, and no way to actually control the TCP segment size in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Melli has great reasoning in their answer about why you'd choose larger or smaller packets.  You're basically trading throughput for responsiveness.

I don't agree that there isn't a correct answer; at least in this case I think there's very obviously a *better* answer: If you want it to arrive at the other end as fast as possible, send it all at once!

- Less system calls to send the data
- Less overhead because you're sending less TCP packets & less redundant headers
- Fragmentation is the responsibility of the lower levels of the network stack, not your application
- The resulting code will be much more simple