# tcp or udp for a game server?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I know, I know. This question has been asked many times before. But I've spent an hour googling now without finding what I am looking for so I will ask it again and mention my context along with what makes the decision hard for me:
I am writing the server for a game where **the response time is very important** and **a packet loss every now and then isn't a problem**.

Judging by this and the fact that I as a server mostly have to send the same data to many different clients, the obvious answer would be UDP.

I had already started writing the code when I came across this:

> In some applications TCP is faster (better throughput) than UDP.
>   This is the case when doing lots of small writes relative to the MTU size. For example, I read an experiment in which a stream of 300 byte packets was being sent over Ethernet (1500 byte MTU) and TCP was 50% faster than UDP.

In my case the information units I'm sending are <100 bytes, which means each one fits into a single UDP packet (which is quite pleasant for me because I don't have to deal with the fragmentation) and UDP seems much easier to implement for my purpose because I don't have to deal with a huge amount of single connections, but **my top priority is to minimize the time between**

```
client sends something to server
```

**and**

```
client receives response from server
```

So I am willing to pick TCP if that's the faster way.
Unfortunately I couldn't find more information about the above quoted case, which is why I am asking: **Which protocol will be faster in my case?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UDP is still going to be better for your use case.

The main problem with TCP and games is what happens when a packet is dropped.  In UDP, that's the end of the story; the packet is dropped and life continues exactly as before with the next packet.  With TCP, data transfer across the TCP stream will stop until the dropped packet is successfully retransmitted, which means that not only will the receiver not receive the dropped packet on time, but subsequent packets will be delayed also -- most likely they will all be received in a burst immediately after the resend of the dropped packet is completed.

Another feature of TCP that might work against you is its automatic bandwidth control -- i.e. TCP will interpret dropped packets as an indication of network congestion, and will dial back its transmission rate in response; potentially to the point of dialing it down to near zero, in cases where lots of packets are being lost.  That might be useful if the cause really was network congestion, but dropped packets can also happen due to transient network errors (e.g. user pulled out his Ethernet cable for a couple of seconds), and you might not want to handle those problems that way; but with TCP you have no choice.

One downside of UDP is that it often takes special handling to get incoming UDP packets through the user's firewall, as firewalls are often configured to block incoming UDP packets by default.  For an action game it's probably worth [dealing with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) that issue, though.

Note that it's not a strict either/or option; you can always write your game to work over *both* TCP and UDP, and either use them simultaneously, or let the program and/or the user decide which one to use.  That way if one method isn't working well, you can simply use the other one, and it only takes twice as much effort to implement.  :)

> In some applications TCP is faster (better throughput) than UDP. This
>   is the case when doing lots of small writes relative to the MTU size.
>   For example, I read an experiment in which a stream of 300 byte
>   packets was being sent over Ethernet (1500 byte MTU) and TCP was 50%
>   faster than UDP.

If this turns out to be an issue for you, you can obtain the same efficiency gain in your UDP protocol by placing multiple messages together into a single larger UDP packet.  i.e. instead of sending 3 100-byte packets, you'd place those 3 100-byte messages together in 1 300-byte packet.  (You'd need to make sure the receiving program is able to correctly intepret this larger packet, of course).  That's really all that the TCP layer is doing here, anyway; placing as much data into the outgoing packets as it has available and can fit, before sending them out.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is very useful!
You mentioned the possibility of increasing the speed by put several information units into a single packet, why would that be more efficient?
Does sending a UDP packet that contains 50 take the same effort as one that contains 500 bytes? Or is it only because you save a few bytes with the fact that you only need 1 packet header for all insead of 1 each?

Comment: There is 52 bytes of bandwidth overhead per UDP packet for the UDP, IP, and Ethernet packet headers (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846139/131930 ) and also a certain number of CPU cycles that must be expended for every packet on every device the packet interacts with (see: http://www.tamos.net/~rhay/overhead/ip-packet-overhead.htm ).  Dunno whether this overhead will be noticeable in your application, but it's definitely non-zero.